# Router Networking

Tags: windows, networking

Got a question on some routing

Have a PC with 3 Nics

Wireless Nic Used for internet 192.168.0.30 gets on intneret fine

Nic 2 Internal Netwrok 192.168.2.200 has static routes for 192.168.3.X,, 4.xx, 5,xx 6.xx, 7.xx 8.xx 9.xx  works great can ping and see all those address

Nic 3 10.0.0.225  trying to see other connections in 10.0.0.0 ie 10.0.0.53, 54, 55, 56.57 Cant get those to work

Have Wirelss set to metric 3

Internal Lan metric 2

Nic 3 local wan metric 1

everything works great other thann local wan

I have a persistent route of 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1

Any Help ??

Comment: Never thought to use inter vlan routing to prevent to multihome your pc like that ?

Comment: Dont know how to do that ??

Comment: This is all for Monitoring 2 independent networks.  the Wireless is there to allow remote access via teamviewer.   just need to monitor the local 192.168.2.X,3.x,4.x etc and the 10.0.0.X

Comment: If nic3 is alone plugged, do you see any traffic by there ?

Comment: Nic 3 goes to the 10.0.0.1 router i had traffic yesterday it would load the config pages at 10.0.0.53 etc albeit slow and today they wont load at all

Comment: plug only that nic, erase your route (route delete *) and test again, I suspect more a route problem, as such after edit your question with a route print

Comment: Please, write in your question all netmasks for each IP address.